# Is it possible to implement an interface extending Traversable?

Tags: php, iterator

I'd like to have iterable objects conforming to an interface but would like to leave the choice of how to implement the iterability (implementing e.g. `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate`) to the implementation.

I thought this might do the trick:

```
interface IsTraversable extends Traversable {
    // some other stuff here
}

class A implements IsTraversable, IteratorAggregate {
    function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator(array());
    }
}
```

but it throws:

```
Class A must implement interface Traversable as part of either Iterator or IteratorAggregate
```

The message is a bit confusing as `IteratorAggregate` is implemented. It seems it's rather trying to tell me that I cannot implement `Traversable` directly.

Is it possible to implement my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend `Traversable`, you need to list `IteratorAggregate` first in the list of implementations. Per the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php):

> This is an internal engine interface which cannot be implemented in PHP scripts. Either IteratorAggregate or Iterator must be used instead. **When implementing an interface which extends Traversable, make sure to list IteratorAggregate or Iterator before its name in the implements clause.**

Emphasis mine. This won't throw an error:

```
<?php
interface IsTraversable extends Traversable {
    // some other stuff here
}

class A implements IteratorAggregate, IsTraversable {
    function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator(array());
    }
}
```